# Не работает ajax на странице с кратким адресом

Tags: asp.net, mvc

Asp.net mvc 5 + jquery. При отладке если адресная строка в браузере имеет вид:  http://localhost:56661/, то на странице не отрабатываются ajax-запросы. 
Например, имеется такая функция:

```
   $('body').on('click', '#infopanel a', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var variety = $("#dosub").attr("variety");
            var data = {variety: variety };
           //
            var url = "subOnVariety";
            $.post(url, data, function (response) {

     });
  });
```

При клике по ссылке на странице отрабатывается весь код до вызова ajax-функции. 
Если же в адресную строку дописать контроллер и метод действия и перейти на эту же страницу по ссылке http://localhost:56661/Main/Index/, кликнуть по нужной ссылке, то все отрабатывается как надо.
На layout странице скрипты подключены так:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryajax")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/myscript")

Регистрация бандлов
  public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
        {
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryajax").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/myscript").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/MyScript.js"));

        }
```

В представлении мастер-страница подключена:

```
@{
 Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```

Вопрос: почему что при краткой строке в браузере, ajax функции не работают?

Comment: что значит не отрабатывается? Запрос с клиента уходит? (можно посмотреть в хроме в табе network) В консоли ошибки есть?

Comment: Хрома пока нет. Не отрабатывается - ставлю точку останова  в методе действия контроллера - не ловится. При втором варианте адресной строки - перехватывается.

Comment: Ставьте хром. Вот статья по поводу как дебажить https://habrahabr.ru/company/ruvds/blog/335758/
Что касается вашей проблемы - из того что я вижу ajax запрос отправляется но контроллер его не матчит. Проверьте настройки роутинга. Они лежат в routeconfig

Comment: У вас webapi  или mvc контроллер? Роутинг в студию.

Answer (score 0):

В общем проблема в построении урла запроса.

Когда вы делаете ajax запрос находясь на странице:

http://localhost:56661/Main/Index/

```
  var url = "subOnVariety";
            $.post(url, data, function (response)
```

запрос уходит на http://localhost:56661/Main/Index/subOnVariety

Когда вы делаете запрос с "короткого адреса", запрос уходит на 
http://localhost:56661/subOnVariety где его никто не ждет.

Это решается либо:

1. Всегда пишем полный url запроса

   var url = "http://localhost:56661/Main/Index/subOnVariety"
2. Правим routeconfig.cs файл что бы наш запрос мог быть корректно отловлен сервером. [Вот](https://metanit.com/sharp/mvc5/6.1.php) статья о том как и что

Comment: Да, полный путь к методу действия - то, что надо. Все работает. Спасибо!

Comment: @AlexeyShmelev С полным путем есть небольшой нюанс. Когда вы пойдете в прод, у вас рут  http://localhost:56661 поменяется. Так что если вы расчитываете на продакшн, то все урлы должны быть вида : 
var url = root+'my/path/to' что бы вы могли рут поменять в одном месте для всех и сразу.

Comment: В моем случае помогло просто указание на контроллер и метод действия, без рута. На хостинге работает тоже.